# Implementing ping/pong for userData websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binance

According to the Binance API: "The websocket server will send a ping frame every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed."

So here's the problem I am having, I do have a websocket implementation however after that 10 minute period, it disconnect. My `on('close')` does not return me anything but I just stop getting any messages from the socket.

This is the code I have to send back the pong:

```
ws.on('ping', (data) => {
    console.log("ping: " + data);
    ws.pong("pong");
    ws.isAlive = true;
    ws.lastAlive = new Date();
});
```

I also tried `ws.send()` but it does not work for me. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my full code: https://playcode.io/356312

And here is the link the the Binance documentation;

websockets: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md

User data: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/user-data-stream.md

Comment: Why instead of use websocket you don't use `socket.io`. All ping-pong stuff are already made for you. You only need to focus in the events

Comment: That's becase the library I am using is already implemented in this manner

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have a Binance websocket for market data, but I can't keep it alive for more than about 25mins before it stops.  There's no error message, the data just stop arriving.  Then a few minutes later the ready-state changes to closed.